# pass view data to custom editor in kendo grid

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I'm looking at an example form the demo website of kendo
http://demos.kendoui.com/web/grid/editing-custom.html

In the asp mvc code sample there is absolutely no reference to   ViewData["categories"] from the controller.

Which black magic is it using to get this data in a dropdownlist in the editor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here as shown in below section they are providing datasource path direct to database and it fetches the value from the database so no magic there everything is using basic code laungage

```
dataSource: {
               type: "odata",
               transport: {
                     read: "http://demos.kendoui.com/service/Northwind.svc/Categories"
                          }
             }
```

and for MVC

```
var categories = dataContext.Categories
                        .Select(c => new ClientCategoryViewModel {
                            CategoryID = c.CategoryID,
                            CategoryName = c.CategoryName
                        })
                        .OrderBy(e => e.CategoryName);
            ViewData["categories"] = categories;
            ViewData["defaultCategory"] = categories.First();
```

and for MVC view :-

```
.Model(model =>
        {
            model.Id(p => p.ProductID);
            model.Field(p => p.ProductID).Editable(false);
            model.Field(p => p.Category).DefaultValue(
                ViewData["defaultCategory"] as Kendo.Mvc.Examples.Models.ClientCategoryViewModel);
        })
```

Comment: i said to look at the asp mvc sample, not at the html sample

Comment: yes, i know categories is assigned to viewdata, but it's never used in the view. the part i dont understand is where in the view it reads the view data

Comment: the viewdata only reads the defaultcatory here, not the categories?

Comment: sorry it binds here columns.Bound(p => p.Category).ClientTemplate("#=Category.CategoryName#").Width(160);

Comment: I'm trying this same thing and have the same question.  Where is ViewData["categories"] actually being picked up from the MVC View?  Neel's responses didn't really provide much in the way of clarification.

Comment: Ok...figured this out.  There is a custom editor that uses the CategoryViewModel as the model and defines the editor using a Kendo().DropDownListFor.  Too bad the docs didn't indicate this CRUCIAL piece anywhere.